# Would like to change audio codec, but keep video settings with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video for which I'd like to convert the audio codec to AAC 320 kbps / 44.100 kHz.  What would I use for ffmpeg switches such that all the video settings and codec remain the same, but only the audio codec and settings change?

Here's my video:

```
$ ffmpeg -i Winnipeg.rb\ Scala-Talk.mov 
FFmpeg version SVN-r25375, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  6 2010 13:02:41 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-shared --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64
  libavutil     50.32. 2 / 50.32. 2
  libavcore      0. 9. 1 /  0. 9. 1
  libavcodec    52.92. 0 / 52.92. 0
  libavformat   52.80. 0 / 52.80. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 2 / 52. 2. 2
  libavfilter    1.48. 0 /  1.48. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2000.00 (2000/1) -> 10.00 (10/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Winnipeg.rb Scala-Talk.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
  Duration: 01:10:53.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 283 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 800x598, 94 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: adpcm_ima_qt, 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16
    Stream #0.2(eng): Audio: adpcm_ima_qt, 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16
At least one output file must be specified
```

Many thanks in advance!  One thing with ffmpeg I've never been able to grok is how to just "tweak" files without having to regurgitate every little setting for things you don't want changed.

Comment: The audio (as well as the video) appears to be fairly low quality. Note that you won't actually increase the quality of the audio by changing format, increasing sampling rate, and increasing bitrate.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

An aggregation of Ehsan's answer with fletom's comment that works for me, thanks to both.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec mp3 -vcodec copy out.avi
```

Comment: just for self reference since I always forget this `-vcodec copy` part

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain it?  Thanks.

Comment: `-i input.avi` specifies the file you want to convert. `out.avi` is the converted file. `-acodec mp3` says to convert the audio stream to mp3 while writing it to the output file. `vcodec copy` says to just copy the video stream into the output file without changing it.

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to change the audio and/or video codec(s) you could just add them as parameters like so:

**Just change the audio codec to mp3** (what ever the original codec was)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 out.avi
```

**Just change the video codec to h264**

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec h264 out.avi
```

It's good to note that ffmpeg must support encoding of the new codec. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377300/what-are-all-codecs-supported-by-ffmpeg

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to add `-vcodec copy` in order to prevent it from trying to transcode my video into h.264. Dunno why it did that by default.

Comment: Yeh the first line actually re-encodes video don't use it

Answer (score 10):

Hard to judge what you are doing, since the ffmpeg command was a bit garbled in your post.

To replace an audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -i normalized.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy new_test.avi
```

More information about the above parameters is found in: [FFmpeg Documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html).

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. When I run `ffmpeg -i old.mkv -i onlySound.m4a out.mkv` the operation takes way longer. Why is that soo?

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use Handbrake which lets keep the video and change the audio and it is a GUI for FFmpeg and it works like a charm.

Comment: HandBrake actually can't do this; it can do a simple copy of audio or subtitle streams, but it *always* re-encodes the video.