# A fast way to convert multiple videos sound from AC3 to AAC without converting video

Tags: audio, video, video-conversion, opencl

Is there a way to convert alot of video files from AC3 sound to AAC? I don't want to convert video iteself, video is okay, only the sound.
I have alot of videos encoded with H.264 or mpeg4(xvid) and AC3 sound, in different containers (.avi, .mkv). I want to convert ONLY sound in them to AAC not touching the video format and container.

Comment: You need to more clearly describe what current situation is, what your problem is, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Check whether it is possible to separate the sound track into a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

**Description**

Convert the audio of multiple video files to AAC with a script in the send to context menu.

**Installation**

1. Download [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)
2. Open the `shell:sendto` folder with the key combination [win]+[r]
3. Create an empty batch file, for instance `aac.bat`
4. Paste the following code `FOR %%i IN (%*) DO ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -c:v copy -c:a aac "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni_aac%%~xi"`

**Usage**

Select the files you want to convert, right click on them, click on "Send to", and click on "aac.bat".

**Result**

The script will create new files where "_aac" is added to the file names and the audio is converted to AAC.

**Assumptions**

I assumed you are running Windows. I tested the script with multiple MKV files with DTS audio on Windows 10.

**FFmpg code**

In case you want to specify the input and output files in another way you can use the code below.

`ffmpeg -i "C:\input.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a aac "C:\output.mkv"`

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to use `FFmpeg` in order to convert only the audio. Then, you can merge the original video and the converted AAC with `MKVToolNix`.

Comment: There is a tutorial here: **[Convert unsupported audio from video](http://ivanrf.com/en/convert-unsupported-audio-from-video/)**.

Comment: You can do all of it with ffmpeg alone: https://superuser.com/questions/215430/would-like-to-change-audio-codec-but-keep-video-settings-with-ffmpeg