# How to re-encode audio of a video file - not touching video stream - ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, audio-conversion

I have a video file but unfortunately the davinci resolve is not able to read audio

I want to re-encode audio

I think aac 192 or mp3 192 would be sufficient

How can I re-encode only audio by using ffmpeg

What is the command?

It has to be constant bitrate not variable

i have tested below commands all fails :/ davinci resolve cant read

```
ffmpeg -i  "input.mkv" -vcodec copy -acodec wav "input wav.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 "input mp3.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s? -c copy -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 384k "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vn "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 192k "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -f "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -f "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -f mkv "input.mkv"
ffmpeg -i "input ogg.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k "input.mkv"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would like to change audio codec, but keep video settings with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/215430/would-like-to-change-audio-codec-but-keep-video-settings-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: @PierU i tested commands there but somehow davinci resolve still cant read audio :/ i think it requires deterministic output not variable

Comment: @PierU i have added the tested commands

Comment: At some point you may also wonder if the problem is not the video stream rather than the audio stream. Please copy/paste the full `ffprobe` output on your original file, and the error message (if any) from davinci.